# Select columns with null values postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a postgreSQL database with 22 table. I need a query which returns the columns with null values. May be a static sql statement that I can launch to each table.

I would be pleased to get some help.

Best.

Comment: Are you looking for dynamic SQL here?  Can you post your database information?  Also, by "database" did you really mean "table?"

Comment: Try with WHERE col1 IS NULL...

Comment: I need one query which returns all the null columns of one table

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` periodically, [pg_stats.null_frac](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html) can help you to get that:

```
--Get columns "filled" entirely with null values
SELECT 
    schemaname,
    tablename,
    attname,
    null_frac 
FROM 
    pg_stats 
WHERE 
    null_frac = 1.0 
    AND schemaname = 'yourschema'
```

Comment: Thank you for you response it does give the columns with null values. If it's possible I want to know if there is a possibility to have the count of these null values per each column?

Comment: You could multiply `pg_stats.null_frac` by `pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup` to get an estimative.

Comment: I did it but doesn't give any result!

Comment: @zakariamouqcit please create another question so we could help you there

Comment: solved the issue, thank you for your assistance and help.

Comment: @zakariamouqcit glad to help you :)